# Converting Varchar Date into Date Datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column storing dates with a datatype of `varchar` in SQL Server. The date is formatted as `Mon-01-Oct` which means `Monday, 1st, October`.

I want to convert it into date format as `dd-mm-yy` (here: `01-10-2018`) while inserting the data into another table.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Should it always be the current year?

Comment: Yes. For now we are working with data from current year only. Thank you.

Comment: Well, both answers currently provided to the question will give you the desired output. My answer depends on regional settings of the SQL Server to translate the month names correctly, the other answer does not.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the year should always by the current year, here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @StringDate char(10) = 'Mon-01-Oct'

SELECT CONVERT(Date, 
               REPLACE(RIGHT(@StringDate, 6), '-', ' ') +' '+ 
               CONVERT(char(4), GETDATE(), 120),
               106) As DateValue
```

Result:

```
2018-10-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
-- `monthes` is a raw data you need to do your convertion
;with monthes as (
    select '10' mn, 'Oct' md
    union all select '11', 'Nov'
    union all select '12', 'Dec'
    union all select '01', 'Jan'
    union all select '02', 'Feb'
    union all select '03', 'Mar'
    union all select '04', 'Apr'
    union all select '05', 'May'
    union all select '06', 'Jun'
    union all select '07', 'Jul'
    union all select '08', 'Aug'
    union all select '09', 'Sep'
)
select parsename(replace(t.dateColumn, '-', '.'), 2) + '-' + m.mn + '-2018' dateString
from yourTable t
left join monthes m 
  on m.md= parsename(replace(t.dateColumn, '-', '.'), 1);
```